# How to print Unicode string using QTextStream?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, unicode, console

I want to print Unicode text into Windows console by using Qt (`QTextStream`). A code page of the console should be set to Unicode by using `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8)` function. However, when I am using a plain way, then the output contains some garbage symbols.

```cpp
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QTextCodec>

#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);

    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTextStream stream(stdout);
    stream.setCodec("UTF-8");

    QString hello = "1 привет 2 привет 3 привет";
    stream << hello << endl;

    QString hello_en = "1 hello 2 hello 3 hello";
    stream << hello_en << endl;

    return a.exec();
}
```

[image: Screenshot with output 1.]
As you can see, after the `hello` string was printed also garbage symbols were printed, which consisted of part of this string. But the `hello_en` string consisting only of ASCII symbols was printed correct.

At the same time, if the codec of `QTextStream` was set to a system locale of console (in my case it is `IBM 866`), then the garbage symbols were not printed.

```cpp
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QTextCodec>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTextStream stream(stdout);
    stream.setCodec("IBM 866");

    QString hello = "1 привет 2 привет 3 привет";
    stream << hello << endl;

    QString hello_en = "1 hello 2 hello 3 hello";
    stream << hello_en << endl;

    return a.exec();
}
```

[image: Screenshot with output 2.]
As you see, non-ASCII symbols are printed correctly.

So, when I am trying to use a `QTextStream` for printing the Unicode string to a Unicode console, then some garbage symbols are appearing in the stdout. Previous questions on Stackoverflow are suggesting a solution without using `QTextStream`.

What am I doing wrong? Or am I using this correctly and this is a bug in Qt and I should report it to the Qt bug tracker?

**UPDATE 1**

This issue become on Qt 5.8.0 MinGW 5.3.0 32-bit on Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit. But, when I tried to use Qt 5.8.0 MSVC2015 on my system, all working well. I am confused. What's wrong? But I can use MSVC2015, because this is not essential.

Comment: Whate are the values returned by the calls to `SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8)` and `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8)` ?

Comment: @BenjaminT both functions are returned `1` after call.

Comment: Tried with Qt 5.8.0 MSVC2015 32 bits on Windows 10 64 bits, I do not have the issue.

Comment: @BenjaminT thanks, I am using Qt 5.8.0 MinGW 5.3.0 32 bit on Win 8.1 Pro 64 bit. I will try to use Qt 5.8.0 MSVC2015 on my system.

Comment: @BenjaminT it's so strange, with Qt 5.8.0 MSVC2015, the issue do not appeared.

Comment: I don't have the issue with MinGW.

Comment: @BenjaminT could you have any idea how to check why the issue is happening?

Comment: My first idea would be to check what happens with different printing method. Like testing printf, cout and Qt classes, trying printing char by char with and without flushing. If it happens only with Qt classes I'd report a bug or use the mailing list. Also if you go testing with printf and cout be sure to have proper UTF-8 string literal encoding in your source.

Comment: @BenjaminT thanks for your advise!